# Is there a way to pin point a drag_to?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I would like to drag an item to near the bottom of a container so that it is added to the bottom of a list.

Like so...

```
source = page.find('#foo')
target = page.find('#bar')
source.drag_to(target, :bottom_center)
```

or

```
source.drag_to(target, 50, 100)
```

Is there a way to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: Did you try `target = page.find('#bar::after')` or `target = page.find('#bar:last-child::after')`?

Comment: does that render the same in xpath?

Comment: No, those are css selectors.

Comment: does xpath have an equivalent?

Comment: Surely, but could you test if these work first?

Comment: @TangibleDream Why the insistence on xpath?  Lots of people seem to want to use xpath all the time with Capybara but it generally ends up with them using ugly, fragile, hard to read selectors.  There are times it's needed, but can you give any incite into why you use it by default?

Comment: ugh -- that should be insight - not trying to start an argument :)

Comment: I find xpath to be a bit more clear than css. consider... ```//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div```  vs. ```html.no-js body div#layout div.row div.column.col-md-9 div.container.well.well-lg.inner-form div.inner.nice-scroll.ko_container.ui-sortable```

Comment: Also I'm coming from a couple of years of Ranorex, which employs a sort of xpath + selector identification.

Comment: lastly, if xpath works more often then css, it would just make sense from a consistency standpoint.

Comment: @TangibleDream The problem there is that the selectors are way too specific and are brittle because of that.  In most sites a selector of just `#layout .ko_container` would probably uniquely locate that element, and if not then scoping to a region of the page using `within` makes more sense than tons of long XPath or CSS selectors

Comment: I try very hard to avoid counted xpaths and use contains where possible '''//*[@id="section-design-element-content"]/div/label[contains(text(),"Page Break")]''' or ```//*[contains(text(),"Sale Code")]/../../td/input```

Comment: XPath doesn't work more often than CSS, it's the other way around. CSS can handle 99% of locators in my experience, it's faster, easier to read, and has better browser support. XPath is for times when you have to find text in an element or some really weird DOM traversal stuff (which is really, really rare).

Comment: @TangibleDream in your XPath vs CSS example, if the DOM changes, you'll never locate your desired DIV with just indexes and a hierarchy. At least with the CSS tags and class names you'll be able to trace a path.

Comment: JeffC, Thomas Walpole I consider myself informed, I'll spend the time to switchout my xpath  to css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Capybara built-in support for drag to a specific offset in an element, all element actions target the centers of elements.  Since you're using selenium you can drop to the driver level and specify an offset, however it means you can't easily swap to another driver

```
page.driver.browser.action.
    click_and_hold(source.native).
    move_to(target.native, 50, 100).
    release.perform
```

Comment: I'll try this, and I'll school myself in converting what I have done to CSS, any good references are welcome.

Comment: @TangibleDream Rather than converting wholesale just start using less restricted CSS selectors (or xpaths, just keep them shorter and less rigid rather than what Chrome tells you the XPath for the element is) and as your pages change (and the highly specific XPaths break you can replace them).  My original question really was just to find out why you thought using XPaths like that was a good idea.  Was it from a blog article somewhere, or other examples?

Comment: Ranorex uses xpath, and I was able to work quicker with what I already knew.  Doing the mass conversion would get css in my head.  Also am I right in thinking that xpath is more used in selenium and other automation, where css is sort of style sheets and automation.  It makes seaching for help a little tricky.  Like googling for 'Capybara' and dodging the zoo links.

Comment: @TangibleDream  Capybara uses xpath internally for its provided "selectors" via the xpath gem -  however it's usually easier and quicker for most users to use CSS when they're looking for elements -  #id vs *[@id='id'],   .some_class vs *[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' some_class ')], etc.  That's why, by default, Capybara defaults to :css for  `find`, `first` , `all`, etc.

Comment: @TangibleDream  don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark), if it has helped you, so the question gets marked as answered

Comment: I will, just ran out of time to test out the answer,  I will definitely do so tomorrow.  I'm also going to ask another question on css, to help me utilize that as a selector

Comment: Had to to tweak y to 550 ```, 150, 550)``` but it worked like a champ!  Thanks Thomas